# Embedded H2 DB is shown as empty in external SQL clients

Tags: spring-boot, h2

I have a Spring Application. 
With an embedded H2 database.

I enabled the access to the H2 via the console 
and tried to enable access via external SQL clients.

Accessing the DB via the console - works. The DB is not empty

[image]
[image]

But when I try to access the DB with an external SQL client - the DB is shown as empty:

[image]

**Question**: how can I make the DB accessible via external SQL clients?

My application.properties

```
# http://localhost:8080/console/
h2.tcp.enabled=false
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:dbname
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=mydbuser
spring.datasource.password=mydbpass
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

My Application.class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
 ...

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }


  /**
   * Start internal H2 server so we can query the DB from IDE
   *
   * @return H2 Server instance
   * @throws SQLException
   */
  @Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
  public Server h2Server() throws SQLException {
    return Server.createTcpServer("-tcp", "-tcpAllowOthers", "-tcpPort", "9092");
  }

}
```

My WebConfiguration

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration {
    @Bean
    ServletRegistrationBean h2servletRegistration(){
        ServletRegistrationBean registrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean( new WebServlet());
        registrationBean.addUrlMappings("/console/*");

        // make the console remotely accessible
        registrationBean.addInitParameter("webAllowOthers", "true");

        return registrationBean;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to expand `PUBLIC` schema? Your DB should be there...

Comment: I tried, the Shema is empty

Comment: Try to compare your app with this [demo](https://github.com/Cepr0/one-h2-two-app). Here are two apps hat work with the same H2DB - first app creates the db and writing data every 1 sec to it (start it first), the second one is reading the data from the db every 5 sec...

Comment: Found out what it was - I used different versions of H2 in my App and in the external SQL client. The H2 related configuration above is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what it was - I used different versions of H2 in my App and in the external SQL client. The H2 related configuration above is correct.